# C# - Trouble fetching webpage - Error: Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#

I copied the code to look exactly like this (http://www.csharp-station.com/howto/httpwebfetch.aspx) - just to see if it was something I was doing wrong. Well still says unable to connect to remote sever :/

Any ideas?

"System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:5555"

Answer (score 0):

And can you connect to it with IE or another webbrowser?

If so I'd guess that it's a firewall/antivirus/security program that's intefering.

Comment: Yes I can connect to interwebz fine. How can I adjust those settings?

Comment: @dave9909 - And you can connect to the exact same site in IE as the one you try to connect to with that code? Depending on what security software you've got installed there might be ways to add an exception for your software, or it might be possible for you to disable it completely for a few minutes to see if it's that that's interfering (don't do this unless you've got some other protection between you and the internet though).